# Changing CSS value/attribute in PHP/JS based on language

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I'm using this method to add multiple languages to my website: http://www.bitrepository.com/php-how-to-add-multi-language-support-to-a-website.html

I'm facing problem where my button name is defined in CSS "content: '';" because of pseudo-class I need.

```
.btn-c:before {
  content: "Send";
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 63px; 
}
.btn-c:hover:before {
  display: none; 
}
.btn-c:hover:after {
  content: "Available for work";
  font-size: 1em;
  color: red; 
}
```

My question is if I can change CSS property based on selected language in PHP. Or is it even better to do it in Js/Jquery? I would be very thankful if someone could help me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Use `data-*` attributes

In PHP echo your *i18n* values into those `data-after` and `data-before` attributes like i.e:

```php
<span class="btn-c"
      data-before="<?= $lang['SEND']; ?>"
      data-after="<?= $lang['AVAILABLE_FOR_WORK']; ?>"></span>
```

than in **CSS** you can get your translations using

`content: attr(data-before);` and  `content: attr(data-after);`

*Example:*

```css
body{background:#666;}

.btn-c:before {
  content: attr(data-before);
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 63px; 
}
.btn-c:hover:before {
  display: none; 
}
.btn-c:hover:after {
  content: attr(data-after);
  font-size: 1em;
  color: red; 
}
```

```html
<span class="btn-c" data-before="Send" data-after="Available for work"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! It works. It was so simple. I have one more question. If I want change other attribute in e.g. :after, let's say font-size. Do I use data-* for it too?

Comment: not trough php. Use css as you're doing already in the :after pseudo

Comment: Alright. I don't want to bother you too much, but I have other question right now. If I want change position from left based on language in here h1 {left:60px;} how could I manage it? I tried :lang() / [lang=""] but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @Joel you can use the lang `lang="de"` attribute and than do in CSS: `h1[lang='de']{left:60px;}` - But you're doing something totally wrong. If you designed your website properly and in know CSS and stuff - you should never ever style CSS depending on words length/width. Go back to the whiteboard, design should be consistent and flexible, not fragile and bugs-prone...